# Creating Simple MVC based Web Application using Node.js

Tags: node.js, rest, model-view-controller, web-applications

I am beginner in node.js and wanted to make small mvc based web app using node.js
I have decent knowledge of MVC model.
So can someone please give me resource link/reference which gives step by step explanation as I am new to node.js.

Thank you.

Comment: Node-school http://nodeschool.io/ is one of the cool way to run node and some more framework like exress.
https://github.com/azat-co/expressworks

Comment: Some useful links are :-
https://github.com/azat-co/expressworks
https://github.com/workshopper/learnyounode

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand 3W (what-why-when) using MVC in your app.

Example - Folder for web app in Nodejs :

> Build a Complete MVC Website With ExpressJS in [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-complete-mvc-website-with-expressjs--net-34168) and example [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/tree/master/examples/mvc)

```
/public
    /images
    /javascripts
    /stylesheets
/routes
    /index.js
    /user.js
/views
    /index.hjs
    /app.js
/package.json
```

Another instruction about MVC detail in Nodejs

> MVC web framework for Node.js designed to make Express easier to use. you can see in [here](https://github.com/kethinov/roosevelt)